# C++ Boost includes gives error C4265

Tags: c++, boost

I have a problem with Boost.

When I'm trying to include f.e:

```
#include <boost\algorithm\string\split.hpp>
```

building fails with an error:

```
boost_1_54_0\boost\exception\exception.hpp(171): error C4265: 'boost::exception_detail::error_info_container' : class has virtual functions, but destructor is not virtual
1>           instances of this class may not be destructed correctly"
```

Any ideas?

This problem occurs both on Visual Studio 2010 and 2012. I have already set include paths in c/c++ additional include directories and also set to 'Not Using Precompiled Headers' in properties.

Comment: It should be a warning, not an error, remove `/WX` option from your compiler settings.

Comment: Not only is it a warning, it's disabled by default.

Comment: I have already set Treat Warning As Errors to: No (/WX-)

Comment: @IgorR. Without luck...

Comment: Go to Propertires-->C/C++-->Command line, copy&paste it here.

Comment: @IgorR. /MP /GS /W4 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /I"..\..\..\include" /I"..\..\..\include\fbxsdk" /I"E:\Moje dokumenty\Dev\VisualStudio\Libs\boost_1_54_0" /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Ob2 /Fd"..\..\..\..\obj\x64\Release\plugins\astoolfbxexporter\vc80.pdb" /fp:precise /D "NDEBUG" /D "_VC80_UPGRADE=0x0710" /D "_WINDLL" /errorReport:prompt /GF /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /MD /EHsc /nologo /Fo"..\..\..\..\obj\x64\Release\plugins\astoolfbxexporter\"

Comment: Now you see: you've got `/W4` and doesn't have '/WX-`. Go to C/C++-->General page and adjust these flags - but make sure you do this for the appropriate configuration! As far as I can see, you compile for x64 Release.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you have 'WX-', I missed it. Then, see the command line for the particular cpp - perhaps it overrides the project command line.

Comment: @IgorR. There is "WX-" :) And I just change back to W4 after trying other levels. On all levels error occurs. Also, all cpp's have the same setting.

Comment: lol @ "Moje dokumenty". Also, slashes should go the other way for compatibility.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Well, we both know that this is not a solution...

Comment: Search the sources (including and especially those of external libraries like that "fbxsdk" you have there) for `#pragma warning`. It may be that some header contains `#pragma warning(error:4265)` to enable and force-error that particular warning. (Strange: I was under the impression that Emil had changed his code to suppress this warning.)

Comment: @SebastianRedl I've just replaced includes, and put include with fbsdk on the last position, and it works. Do not know why though... :D Thanks for leading me into the solution!